# Why cant Jquery select an image by Id without name when accessing an attribute?

Tags: jquery, image, attr

I have the following code:

```js
function myfun(arg) {
  var info = $(arg).attr("myinfo");
  $('#output').html((typeof info) + ": " + info);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="A" myinfo="kittens" src="https://placekitten.com/200/200">
<img id="B" name myinfo="kittens" src="https://placekitten.com/200/200">
<ul>
  <li>
    <button onclick="myfun(A)">Doesn't Work</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="myfun(B)">Works</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<p id="output">Output here</p>
```

When I try to access the attribute `myinfo` in image Id `A`, I am unable to select the image Id to access `myinfo` using jQuery.

However if the name property is present then I am easily able to select `myinfo` using the same syntax. It doesn't matter if I specify a particular name, even a blank one works.

What is going on here? I tried accessing with `$("#" + arg).attr("myinfo");` and that did not work either.

Here is a link to the JSFiddle also : [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/8dm3j9f1/1/)

Comment: You're relying on the browser to set `window.A` and `window.B` for you, based on the `id` of the elements, which isn't a great idea to start with. However, for some reason the reference to `A` alone does not work unless it has a `name` attribute (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8dm3j9f1/5/) - `window.A` is undefined). I'm unsure why that is though. Also note that `myinfo` is not a valid attribute so your HTML is invalid, which can cause issues in IE and older browsers. If you want to store custom information with an element use a `data-*` attribute

Comment: It's even more confusing when the `name` attribute on the `img` element is deprecated according to the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html). I can only think this is a browser oddity given your strange use of passing global element references around.

Comment: The strange thing is that this only seems to be a problem in the `onclick` attribute. If I set a breakpoint in `myfun`, I can access `A` in the JS debugger.

Comment: Simple pass myfun( '#A' ) instead of myfun(A)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quote marks around `'A'` and `'B'` in your function calls, and use `'#'+arg` as the selector.

```js
function myfun(arg) {
 var info = $('#'+arg).attr("myinfo");
  $('#output').html((typeof info)+": "+info + ' ' + arg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="A" myinfo="kittens" src="https://placekitten.com/200/200">
<img id="B" name myinfo="kittens" src="https://placekitten.com/200/200">
<ul>
<li><button onclick="myfun('A')">Doesn't Work</button></li>
<li><button onclick="myfun('B')">Works</button></li>
</ul>
<p id="output">Output here</p>
```

As @Rory McCrossan and @Barmar have mentioned in the comments, this can also be achieved by accessing the elements as properties of the window object with `window[arg]`.

```js
function myfun(arg) {
  var info = $(window[arg]).attr("myinfo");
  $('#output').html((typeof info)+": "+info + ' ' + arg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="A" myinfo="kittens" src="https://placekitten.com/200/200">
<img id="B" name myinfo="kittens" src="https://placekitten.com/200/200">
<ul>
<li><button onclick="myfun('A')">Doesn't Work</button></li>
<li><button onclick="myfun('B')">Works</button></li>
</ul>
<p id="output">Output here</p>
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning in your answer that you ALSO changed the way the jQuery selector is working - you are prepending the `#` to make it select the ID....

Comment: Note that the OP is attempting to pass the `window.A` and `window.B` references of the elements to the function.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - fair enough, but where are those being set? This is a method that I'm not aware of, and would really love to understand if it's a valid / decent practice.

Comment: IDs normally become global variables (elements of the `window` object). http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks! Is that considered good practice / a good pattern - to rely on them?  Seems trivial to explicitly call the appropriate ID in the selector, at least in this case.

Comment: No, I don't think it's common or considered good coding style.

Comment: But it's still strange that it doesn't work as a global variable, since those are the same as accessing properties of `window`.

Comment: Reading this it would seem that it only adds the element to the window object if there is an attribute for ID as well as the attribute for name https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#dom-window-nameditem-filter which would explain why B is being added to the window properties however A is not.

Comment: A returns the element in the console of this page once you have run the code snippet, just to add to the confusion. Maybe it's down to the browser.